# How to automatically copy rows to another sheet in excel based on color in excel without Visual Basic?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to copy a selected column based on the color of a cell (colored using conditional formatting rules) to another sheet in excel. I have seen several posts doing this using VB. However is there a simpler way to do this without writing code in visual basic?

Comment: Filter by color and copy visible cells?

Comment: Is that the only way? I wanted to do it automatically using formulas but not using visual basic code.

Comment: Without a sample of your conditional formatting rules, it's pretty hard (i.e. impossible) to suggest a formula that would work.

Comment: Example of a condition I am using is `=AND($L2<=$AF$2,ABS($AC2)>$AF$4,$Z2<$AF$3)`

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the dynamic array formula `FILTER`?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't see it in the list of functions. I am using Excel 2017 on mac.

Comment: Then you're going to have to use an array formula and it won't necessarily be simpler than just using VBA.

Comment: Okay, thank you for taking the time to help out!