# Copying based on cell color does not work using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy rows based on the cell color to a different sheet in excel.
My code is below. But it's not copying. What am I doing wrong?

`

```
Sub Button1_Click()

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy

        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

        b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

`

Comment: I'd guess the colour in the cell isn't `RGB(255,0,0)`. Have you stepped through your code  to see what it's doing? and/or checked the colour is correct? (In immidiate window: `?Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color`)

Comment: Conditional formatting?  If Yes you need to use DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

Comment: Thank you, DisplayFormat.Interior.Color did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138614/how-to-automatically-copy-rows-to-another-sheet-in-excel-based-on-color-in-excel), I'm guessing you are working with conditional formatting.

In that case, you have to use `Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`.

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
```

Note that you should also [avoid `Select` and `Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).